# In my Simplenews twig template how do I get the URL of the page I am emailing?

Tags: theming

When a single test newsletter is sent, Drupal provides me with the expected URL as follows:

```
{% set foo = url('<current>') %}
<p class="link-to-page">
<a href="{{ foo|render|replace({'simplenews':  ""}) }}">{{ 'You can view this news article in your web browser' }}</a>
</p>
```

Or by using the `trim` Twig  function

But when sending the actual newsletter issue to subscribers, the batch process causes the `url(‘current’)` to provide a batch url like `https://my-site.uk/batch`

How can I obtain the one I want (to direct newsletter recipients to the page). Will a preprocess theme function see the same `url` values as twig or can I reliably capture the node’s real URL there Somehow?

Answer (score 1):

This is better!

```
<p class="link-to-page">
  <a href=" {{ url('entity.node.canonical', {'node': node.id}) }}">
      You can view this news article in your web browser
  </a>
</p>
```